# How can I add background app refresh to swift WatchOs App

Tags: swift, swift2, watchkit, background-process, watchos-2

I have been looking for tutorials to help me to understand how I can add background app refresh for swift into my watch app, so that my Glance will have fairly up to date data (like the weather app).

So far I haven't found anything and wondered if anyone knew of any advice/examples/tutorials that might benefit me.

Comment: Keep in mind that there is a limit to the number of times that your complication can refresh itself throughout the day.

Comment: Yeah I get that there's a limit, ideally I would want to running background refresh to get data then when the glance loads data is fairly accurate and then does a check and updates itself

Answer (score 0):

You could update your watch app with `func updateApplicationContext(_ applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) throws`.

> Use this method to transfer a dictionary of data items to the counterpart app. The system sends context data when the opportunity arises, with the goal of having the data ready to use by the time the counterpart wakes up. The counterpart’s session delivers the data to the session:didReceiveUpdate: method of its delegate. A counterpart can also retrieve the data from the receivedApplicationContext property of its session.
>   [updateApplicationContext:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/updateApplicationContext:error:)

This method sends the data in a background task. When the data arrives you could save it in`userDefault` or in a class that could be read from your Glance, when your Glance `willActivate` is called just update the UI with the latest data that arrived in the `context`.